# Java ProcessBuilder Passing parameters

Tags: java, shell, processbuilder

I have a shell script with one parameter, as follow:

test.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Shell Demo";
echo "Hello $0";
```

Now I want to execute this script using ProgressBuilder and pass parameters. The java code as follow:

```java
 public void testShell() throws Exception {
        String shPath = "./test.sh";
        // want to pass a value "Jack" to shell script
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(shPath, "Jack");
        Process result = builder.start();
        result.waitFor();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getInputStream()));
        String output;
        while ((output = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Shell Demo
Hello ./test.sh
```

The output I want is:

```
Shell Demo
Hello Jack
```

Comment: try print $1 as $0 will always be script/program name in unix

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to remove that `result.waitFor` and also specify the executor to use, i.e) bash (you can also use sh), other than that you're on the right path.

```
public String[] createExecutionString(String process, String...params) {
    final List<String> executor = new ArrayList<>();
    executor.add("bash"); /* cmd on windows */
    executor.add("-c"); /* /c on windows */
    executor.add(process);
    for (String param : params) {
        executor.add(param);
    }
    return executor.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public void testShell() throws Exception {
    String shPath = "./test.sh";
    // want to pass a value "Jack" to shell script
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(createExecutionString(shPath, "Jack"));
    Process result = builder.start();
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getInputStream()));
    String output;
    while ((output = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```